# addEventListener adding again and again

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, gallery

My pictures gallery has 8 frames. There are a few lines of AS3 on the AS3 layer in the first frame:

```
stop();

var picsArrayYouthVillage:Array = new Array(pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic5,pic6,pic7,pic8);
for each (var pic in picsArrayYouthVillage)
{
pic.buttonMode = true;
}



for(var i = 0; i<8; i++)
{

trace("hi");
picsArrayYouthVillage[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, jumpToFrame);

}

function jumpToFrame(m:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop(m.target.name + "_frame");

}
```

On the Pictures layer there are 8 frames containing pictures and thumbnail buttons (pic1,...pic8)

The problem is when I navigate using the thumbs, every time I click the first button and jumping to frame 1, the event listeners are added again.

Any ideas? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check the object has the event listener or not before add event listener to it

```
for(var i = 0; i<8; i++) {

  if (!picsArrayYouthVillage[i].hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK)) {
       trace("hi");
       picsArrayYouthVillage[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, jumpToFrame);
  }

}
```

**EDIT**

After I tried the code, I have found the problem,change this code too

```
var picsArrayYouthVillage:Array = new Array(pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic5,pic6,pic7,pic8);
```

to

```
var picsArrayYouthVillage:Array;

if (picsArrayYouthVillage == null) {
     picsArrayYouthVillage = new Array(pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic5,pic6,pic7,pic8);
}
```

Remember to trace hi in the if condition. If it works, it should eight hi and only one time.

Comment: I tried this, but it still adds those evtListeners. it traces those 8 extra "hi" in output window when I go to frame 1.